# What is supervised sequence labeling?

Tags: machine-learning, supervised-learning

I am now reading Alex Graves PhD thesis.It is fantastic work, but I still need some explanations.I am not sure that I understand sequence labeling.For example,[wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_labeling)
says that
 sequence labeling is a type of pattern recognition task that involves the algorithmic assignment of a categorical label to each member of a sequence of observed values
If we have feature vector with this values

211,212,300,242,243,454,478,321,212,210,510,388,212,211,499,397,406,277

How should the algorithm work in this cases?
I am interested in `211,212` pair,how to set categorical label?
Any ideas are welcome, escpecially with some examples.